# Менять кнопки в зависимости от роли пользователя

Tags: php

Кнопки должны были меняться в зависимости от роли пользователя.
но у меня они не меняются. Что не так? Что неправильно написал?

```
<table class="table">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Имя</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Действия</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
            <?php
            $users = Database::getInstance()->query("SELECT * FROM users");
            foreach ($users->results() as $data) :
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $data->id; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $data->username; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $data->email; ?></td>

                <td>
                    <?php


                        if ($user->hasPermissons('admin')){
                            echo '<a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Разжаловать</a>';
                        }else{
                            echo '<a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Назначить администратором</a>';
                        }
                    
                    ?>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-info">Посмотреть</a>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning">Редактировать</a>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="return confirm('Вы уверены?');">Удалить</a>
                </td>
            </tr>

            </tbody>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </table>
```

Comment: Откуда у вас взялась переменная `$user`? Что в ней лежит?

Answer (score 0):

Судя по всему, ошибка в строке

> `$user->hasPermissons('admin')`

должно быть

> `$data->hasPermissons('admin')`

Ну и возможно есть опечатка в методе `hasPermissions`.